# try all PIDs in linux

Tags: linux

I want to Try in order PIDs instead of a specific PID
for example in this instruction:

```
 perf stat -p <PID> -e cycles,instructions,cache-references,cache- 
misses,bus-cycles -a sleep 10

 #this is example of 1 specefic PID
 perf stat -p 3347 -e cycles,instructions,cache-references,cache-misses,bus-cycles -a sleep 10
```

I want to try all PID's but I don't know what should I write instead of < PID > to try all PIDs.

Comment: `for pid in 1 2 3 4; do perf stat -p "$pid" -e cycles.....; done` - Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: You don't have to provide a pid. The `-p` is not required.

Comment: yeah , I want to test all PIDs. Can you write full instruction for me please? @Haxiel

Comment: And can I write this instruction in terminal? @Haxiel

Comment: @megan So you want to run this command for every PID on your system?

Comment: yes  after run  top command I want to do this @Haxiel

Comment: Using bash you can try `for pid in {1..32768}; do whatever command; done`. FYI, yur pid list will change between the time you exit `top` and start the loop.

Comment: @megan I reviewed some info about the perf command. So the way you're running it, you are trying to attach to an existing process and also profile the `sleep 10` command. I'm not sure those two approaches can be mixed together. What kind of output are you getting here, and what are you trying to achieve with `perf stat`?

Comment: yeah , I want to write bash script but I am a beginner.  Can you write full instruction. What should I write in bash?@doneal24

Comment: Look, I want to write a bash script that tests all the PIDs, it tests  first one and after 10 seconds test nextone. Then I want to put this in a text file. But because I am beginner, I don't know how @Haxiel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to iterate over *all* pids running on your system (need `/proc` dir, unlike `Mac/*BSD`):

```
for pid in /proc/[0-9]*; do printf '%s\n' "${pid##*/}"; done
```

So:

```
for pid in /proc/[0-9]*; do
    perf stat -p "${pid##*/}" -e cycles,instructions,cache-references,cache-misses,bus-cycles -a 2>&1 >> perf.txt
    sleep 10 
done
```

If instead you want the processes that takes the much resources based on `top`, there's a way:

```
for pid in $(top -bn1 | awk '/ PID /{p=1;next}(p==1){print $1}'); do ...
```

Remove `n1` of `top` for `Mac/*BSD`.

Comment: Oh, thanks. This is what I want. And can you please tell me how can I put the output in the 
 txt file?

Comment: You just have to redirect the command line like: `perf ...... > ${pid##*/}.log`

Comment: Can you write full instruction please? I'm confused. for example my txt file name is pid.txt. How to put outputs in this txt file? @Gillas Quenot

Comment: Added solution with the `top` command

Comment: but after run, the txt file is empty.Do you know why? @Gilles Quenot

Comment: Maybe a problem with `tee`. Can you retry with snippet in edited post ?

Comment: the txt file is empty again

Comment: Check edited post